# How to pack an installed ubuntu system into an ISO file?

Tags: system-installation, backup

I find an image on AWS in ami format which is my target.

I need to download the target OS image to my local system and install it on my local cluster computers.
(There is no direct support for exporting ami image into iso file.)

Is it possible? How can I achieve it?